# React - Django Rest Framework - Nested Form Items

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, nested

I have a react form with an nested array of items. When i try to submit the form via DRF i receive a 400 status error detailing that the Item, Delivery Date, Description and Quantity fields are required.

The models are setup so that i have a separate model for for the MaterialRequsitions and MeterialRequsitionItems

On Submit Function (frontend)

```
                    onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                        const formData = new FormData();
                        console.log('Material Requsition Form Values:', values);

                        // Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
                        //     if ( key !== 'upload_documents'  ){
                        //         formData.append(key, values[key]);
                        //     }
                        // });
                        formData.append('project', values.project);
                        formData.append('title', values.title);
                        formData.append('buyer', values.buyer);
                        formData.append('date', values.date);
                        formData.append('requested_by', values.requested_by);


                        // values.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                        //     // Convert each item object to JSON string
                        //     formData.append(`items[${index}]`, (item));
                        // });


                        values.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                            Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
                                formData.append(`items[${index}].${key}`, item[key]);
                            });
                        });


                        // values.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                        //     Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
                        //         formData.append(`items.${index}.${key}`, item.item);
                        //     });
                        // });

                        formData.append('user', userId);
                        console.log(Array.from(formData.entries()));
                        const uploadedFiles = uppy.getFiles();


                        uploadedFiles.forEach((file, index) => {
                            console.log(`File ${index}: `, file);
                            formData.append(`upload_documents[${index}]`, file.data, file.name);
                        });

                        console.log('Form Data:', values);
                        console.log(Array.from(formData.entries()));
                        dispatch(addMaterialRequsition(formData))
                        .unwrap()
                        .then((result) => {
                            console.log('Material Requsition Added Sucessfully:', result);
                            alert('Material Requsition Added Sucessfully');
                            onClose();
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log('Failed to add Material Requsition:', error);
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            setSubmitting(false);
                        });


                    }}
```

Error Message

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item": [
                "This field is required."
            ],
            "description": [
                "This field is required."
            ],
            "quantity": [
                "This field is required."
            ],
            "delivery_date": [
                "This field is required."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Serializers

```
#Material Requsitions
    
class MaterialRequisitionDocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequisitionDocuments
        fields = '__all__'

    
class MaterialRequsitionItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequsitionItems
        fields = ['id', 'item', 'description', 'quantity', 'delivery_date']



class MaterialRequisitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = MaterialRequsitionItemsSerializer(many=True)
    documents = MaterialRequisitionDocumentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    upload_documents = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField(), write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequisition
        fields = ['id', 'number', 'project', 'title', 'buyer', 'date', 'requested_by', 'approved_by', 'status', 'items', 'documents', 'upload_documents', 'user']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        upload_documents = validated_data.pop('upload_documents', None)

        requisition = MaterialRequisition.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for item_data in items_data:
            MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.create(material_requisition=requisition, **item_data)

        if upload_documents is not None:
            for document in upload_documents:
                MaterialRequisitionDocuments.objects.create(material_requisition=requisition, document=document)
        return requisition
    
    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        # Update the MaterialRequisition instance
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()

        # Existing item IDs
        existing_item_ids = set(MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.filter(material_requisition=instance).values_list('id', flat=True))

        # Update the nested items
        for item_data in items_data:
            item_id = item_data.get('id', None)
            if item_id:
                try:
                    item_instance = MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.get(id=item_id, material_requisition=instance)
                    for attr, value in item_data.items():
                        setattr(item_instance, attr, value)
                    item_instance.save()
                    existing_item_ids.discard(item_id)  # Remove this ID from the set
                except MaterialRequsitionItems.DoesNotExist:
                    # Handle the case where item does not exist
                    # e.g., raise an error or continue
                    pass
            else:
                # For new items
                MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.create(material_requisition=instance, **item_data)

        # Delete items that are no longer present
        MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.filter(material_requisition=instance, id__in=existing_item_ids).delete()

        return instance
```

Views

```
class MaterialRequisitionDocumentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MaterialRequisitionDocumentSerializer
    
class MaterialRequisitionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    queryset = MaterialRequisition.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MaterialRequisitionSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(request.data)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

            # Your WebSocket logic here
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                "material_requisition_group",
                {
                    "type": "material_requisition_message",
                    "message": serializer.data
                }
            )

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
    
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            instance = self.get.object()
            requisition_id = instance.id

            self.perform_destroy(instance)


            #Send the deleted diary entry to the channel layer

            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                "material_requisition_group",
                {
                    "type": "material_requisition_message",
                    "message":{
                        "requisition_deleted": requisition_id

                    }
                }
            )

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'detail': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)



class MaterialRequsitionItemsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
    queryset = MaterialRequsitionItems.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MaterialRequsitionItemsSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            print(request.data )
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            self.perform_create(serializer)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

            # Your WebSocket logic here
            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                "material_requisition_group",
                {
                    "type": "material_requisition_message",
                    "message": serializer.data
                }
            )

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Models

```
#Material Requsitions
class MaterialRequisition(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(ConstructionProject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    buyer = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = models.DateField()
    requested_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    status_choices = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('In Progress', 'In Progress'),
        ('Approved', 'Approved'),
        ('Rejected', 'Rejected'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=status_choices, default='Pending')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            latest_entry = MaterialRequisition.objects.filter(project=self.project).order_by('-number').first()
            self.number = latest_entry.number + 1 if latest_entry else 1
        super(MaterialRequisition, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.project} - {self.number}"
    

class MaterialRequsitionItems(models.Model):
    material_requisition = models.ForeignKey(MaterialRequisition, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')
    item = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.material_requisition} - {self.item}"
```

Payload

1. **project:**

   4
2. **title:**

   yyy
3. **buyer:**

   yyy
4. **date:**

   7777-07-07
5. **requested_by:**

   7
6. **items[0].item:**

   0
7. **items[0].description:**

   7
8. **items[0].quantity:**

   7
9. **items[0].unit:**

   7
10. **items[0].delivery_date:**

    7777-07-07
11. **items[0].status:**

    Pending
12. **user:**

    1

I tried varying how the items have been appended to the form.